# Display related products filtered by product attribute in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, custom-taxonomy

I want to display related products filtered by an attribute, that it should be equal to a value from page cookies.

I edit related.php template to look like that:

```
<?php woocommerce_product_loop_start(); ?>

<?php foreach ( $related_products as $related_product ) :
    // extract attribute filter_location in an array
    $results = $related_product->get_attribute( 'pa_filter_location' );

    // extract value from cookies filter_location
    $fl = $_COOKIE['filter_location'];

    foreach ( $results as $key ) {
        if( $key == $fl ) {
            $post_object = get_post( $related_product->get_id() );

            setup_postdata( $GLOBALS['post'] =& $post_object );

            wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' );
        }
    }

endforeach; ?>

<?php woocommerce_product_loop_end(); ?>
```

But I get the error: Warning:

> **Invalid argument supplied for foreach()**

What can be the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem comes from this line:

```
$results = $related_product->get_attribute( 'pa_filter_location' );
```

**That is not giving an array**, but a coma separated string of terms. So you **can't use it in your foreach loop** this way.

Instead use the following revisited code:

```
<?php woocommerce_product_loop_start(); ?>

<?php foreach ( $related_products as $related_product ) :
    // extract attribute filter_location in an array
    $terms = $related_product->get_attribute( 'pa_filter_location' );

    // Set each term in an array
    $terms = ! empty($terms) ? (array) explode(', ', $terms) : array();

    foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
        if( isset($_COOKIE['filter_location']) && $term == $_COOKIE['filter_location'] ) {
            $post_object = get_post( $related_product->get_id() );

            setup_postdata( $GLOBALS['post'] =& $post_object );

            wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' );
        }
    }

endforeach; ?>

<?php woocommerce_product_loop_end(); ?>
```

It should definitively solve your error related to the foreach loop.

Comment: This have fix the error related to the foreach loop. But the script doesn't return any results, there is a missing link between $term and $related product.

Comment: I can display the value of $_COOKIE['filter_location'] without problems. The problem is that i'm trying to display $related_products, but after we extract attributes in $terms array, the link to $related_products get lost.

Comment: @mywebhostel I repeat: my answer here just solve your question problem which is **Invalid argument supplied for foreach()** and should be accepted as it solve this specific problem. Now If you have something else to ask, It should be better asking a new question giving the new necessary details to get helped.